# Is there any gain from storing comments and replies on separate tables instead of a unary relation on a comment table?

Tags: mysql, database

Choice 1:
comments {commentid,replyto,comment}
//replyto will be null on many posts

Choice 2:
comments {commentid,comment}
replies {replyid, replyto, reply}

It looks like a matter of choice rather than linear benefit analysis at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact this is not 'only' matter of choice, but aware decision. Relational databases are not good at solving problems of hierarchical nature. There were tons of discussions, articles, and even books about that, so lets narrow the problem to your case.

The second choice would work fine ONLY if you were to allow replies to comments, and not to replies itself, thus this would be a tree with maximum 2 levels. That might be ok, but if you were to do that better solution would be to place everything with COMMENTS table, and add two columns: THREAD_ID (all the comments with the same THREAD_ID would belong to same thread), SEQ_NUM (or simply DATE would tell us which comment was first). Similar way of organising comments is implemented here on SO.

The first choice is quite simple and generic - but implements recurention with all its cons. Lets stop a bit and think... note that we are actually NOT building a tree, but a 'forest'. We will have many commen threads and every single thread will be a separate tree - relatively small amount of data to organise. In that case I would add a THREAD_ID column to COMMENTS table and use only that table (it would be also good to set an composite index on COMMENTS table containing THREAD_ID and COMMENTID columns - in exactly that order).

So upon above I would choose "choice 1".

Next decision should be about where to do the processing and comment tree construction? I would just get all the comments from the table an organise them on a controller (MVC) side, i.e. JAVA or C++. Traversing the list of comments and building the tree in Main Memory (using objects and pointers or hash tables) would be an easy thing. It is a good option also because small amount of nodes (comments and replies within one thread).

Answer (score 2):

The first option looks like a simple one, but the problem is that you're building a tree-structure in SQL.
and SQL does not support hierarchical data.

**Not recommended - ever**

```
TABLE comment
-------------
id unsigned integer auto_increment primary key,
reply_to unsigned integer, 
comment text,
foreign key FK_comment_reply_to(reply_to) references comment.id 
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

**Recommended - if you want a tree 2 levels deep**

If you build it using 2 tables

```
TABLE main_post
----------------
id unsigned integer auto_increment primary key,
body text,

TABLE reply
-------------
id unsigned integer auto_increment primary key,
reply_to unsigned integer, 
body text,
foreign key FK_reply_reply_to(reply_to) references main_post.id 
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Then you are building a much simpler structure that can be easily queried in SQL because the tree is only 1 level deep.
For this reason I'd recommend choice number 2.

**Alternatives for deeper trees**

If you want a hierarchical structure I'd look at nested sets insteads, see:
http://www.pure-performance.com/2009/03/managing-hierarchical-data-in-sql/

Comment: What about the situation when you are replying to a reply (although the above foreign key prevents this, and requires you to always reply to the original post). You end up moving the bulk of the burden from the main_post to the reply table.

Comment: nested sets are only sane for static structures, due to the need for keeping all references in the tree ordered. That doesn't sound like it would ever fit the bill for an arbitrarily-deep hierarchy of comments and replies.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Queries against the TEXT table were always 3 times slower than those against the VARCHAR table (averages: 0.10 seconds for the VARCHAR table, 0.29 seconds for the TEXT table). The difference is 100% repeatable.**

```
CREATE TABLE varcharTable (a varchar(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (a)) ENGINE=MyISAM; 
CREATE TABLE textTable (a text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (a(255))) ENGINE=MyISAM; 

mysql> explain SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE count(*) from varcharTable where a LIKE "n%"; 
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+ 
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra | 
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+ 
| 1 | SIMPLE | varcharTable | range | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 257 | NULL | 5882 | Using where; Using index | 
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+ 
1 row in set (0.00 sec) 


mysql> explain SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE count(*) from T where a LIKE "n%"; 
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+ 
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra | 
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+ 
| 1 | SIMPLE | T | range | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 257 | NULL | 5882 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+ 
1 row in set (0.00 sec) 


Index is being used for the VARCHAR table, but not for the TEXT table (in the Extra column)
```

**2) search is not required on comments table.So, querying is not required and since its long too. Its type is preferred to be `text`
And then since its text you cannot search on it** .So, put the comments(non-searchable and affecting performance) and replies on separate table. So, that the replies table will function good and the comments table will be kept just for storage purpose, no search performed on them.

**Conclusion:** So, put them the Comments table in a separate table.

Comment: That's correct Angelin, but only when there is an index on a column, and DBMS is able to perform Prefix Search (which means no '%' at the beginning). Try to compare times for a '%n' string.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends very much on what you're trying to achieve with this, from what I can understand if you want a max 2-level tree you should go with choice 2, if you want a deeper tree go with choice 1 with the following modification
Choice 1: comments {commentid,toplevelcommentid | thread | (whatever parent this comment and possibly other comments is/are linked to so you can easily recreate the structure afterwards),replyto,comment}
and when displaying results select everything that has commentid or toplevelcommentid equal to a value and order by commentid so you can easily recreate the structural data with a single select query